# Warning when running wsdl2h

Tags: wsdl, onvif, oasis

Referring to [OASIS wsn](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/) standard web services used when implementing connection to Onvif cameras, when I run

```
wsdl2h bw-2.wsdl
```

I get the following warning and no binding class is created:

> Warning: WSDL "WS-BaseNotification" has no bindings to implement operations

In another words, when I do the same with [Onvif wsdl's](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications) like [device.wsdl](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl) it generates binding class DeviceBindingProxy. Sure, then I generate the CPP codes for this class by soapcpp2 to achieve this. But the problem now is that the warning is issued by wsdl2h and I think this may be the clue to find out what's wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the event part from `event.wsdl`, it will import all the necessary stuff.